# HTML - Special letters bolded/highlighted?

Tags: html, css, character-encoding

I made a language nav on my page. English, Russian and Swedish are the languages, and the titles are in their own languages.

The normal alphabets on English and Swedish show just fine, but the Russian letters seem to bee bold/highlighted, like it would be selected.

[image: Russian letters higlighted]

```css
#lang {}

#lang a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  line-height: 0.9em;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

#lang a.icon:before {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav id="lang">
  <a href="#en" class="fa fa-flag"><span>In English</span></a>
  <a href="#rus" class="fa fa-flag"><span>По русски</span></a>
  <a href="#swe" class="fa fa-flag"><span>På Svenska</span></a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine, [Demo](http://jsbin.com/oPAXAhex/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: That's weird... See at http://artotek.fi. Sorry it looks like a mess atm.

Comment: @user109899 Letters are overlapping on the website you mentioned

Comment: Your font 'Source Sans Pro' does not come with Russian characters, and it falls back to sans-serif, most likely arial, which looks bolder.

Comment: It's related to your font. Try another one.

Comment: Its related to your font, reduce the weight of that particular font

Comment: Well that explains... I was going to make a russian version of the page, but with a different font it'd look stupid. Are there any similar fonts that support russian?

Comment: Sine you are using Google fonts, try looking for fonts that come with [cyrillic character set](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IqLZy.png).

Comment: Changing font-weight doesn't help. I tried to apply it to the span with the Russian letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your font does not support Russian characters, and so the browser is falling back to a font that does. The font that it falls back to is not the same thickness as Source Sans, so it looks bold. You will need to either choose a font that supports both Cyrillic and Roman letters, or find a Cyrillic font that goes well with Source Sans.

See [here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/language/cyrillic) for some suggestions. (For some reason it refers to Cyrillic as a language, but it has good suggestions.)

Comment: In Google Web Fonts, you can select “Sans Serif” in the “Filters” menu and “Cyrillic” in the “Script” menu to find some alternatives, such as Open Sans.

Comment: I wish they would allow you to select multiple character sets at once, but unfortunately that is not the case. Most fonts probably include the latin characters if they have cyrillic, though.